# Python/Discord: Role not found

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

This is my code I'm using to get a hand of adding roles so I can lock put channels:

```
if message.content == "Test":
    member = message.author
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id="Character-Created")
    await member.add_roles(member, role)
```

However, when I run the command I get this error message:
discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10011): Unknown Role

Comment: Replace `id=` with `name=`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change `id` parameter to `name`, so the new code must be like this:

```
if message.content == "Test":
member = message.author
role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="Character-Created")
await member.add_roles(role)
```